# Full web page Screen shot

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, plugins

I want to take **screen shot of full web page** on button click, without scroll bar.I tried using Capture page, but i was not successful.Can someone help me with this??

Comment: Are you trying to provide this as a feature of a website you're developing, or could the solution be an existing app that would allow you to capture any website?  Because I know I have seen the latter.

Comment: We are trying to add this feature to our website,so that user can get full page screenshot of the page he is currently viewing.

Comment: Okay.  That's trickier.  Bowing out.

Comment: Googled it out of curiosity, found this: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: That worked well... But how do I get this content printed in separate pages...

Comment: All the content gets printed in same page... I would like to separate in two pages